# NPM install global confusion

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

```
npm install css-sprite --save

npm install css-sprite -g
```

What does 2 different command above do? I know -g is global, but why do you want it to be global? What's --save?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `npm install MODULE --save` will add the module's name and information directly into your `package.json` file. It is a shortcut from writing the dependency first in your `package.json` and then doing `npm install` (which reads the file and installs all dependencies).
- `npm install MODULE -g` will make sure the module is accessible everywhere in your system, not just in your project's directory. The purpose of this, is that some modules can be used in a "standalone" way, without NodeJS. For example, module Jade is a template engine for HTML. I write all my HTML files in Jade (syntax), and then I call `jade myfile.jade` to render HTML files. I can only call jade freely in the console after installing it globally through npm.

Comment: What if I do npm install module without the --save? I still don't get why is it --save, not --something_else, is that a snytax?

Comment: If you remove the `--save`, npm will install your module without modifying `package.json`. What's wrong with that ? `package.json` is the file containing all dependencies for your project, it has to be exact and up to date at all times. If there are differences between your `package.json` file and the actual modules you have in `/node_modules`, you will get many unwanted surprises when moving your project in remote locations.
Imagine when you travel, you keep a list of everything you packed. The items you actually packed better be on the list, or else you will get confused at some point.

Comment: so --save is consider compulsory, can it be --something_else ??

Comment: I didn't really get your second question about why `--save` and not `--something_else`, I hope my previous comment brightens the subject and answers your question.

Comment: what is --save? is this a node's snytax?

Comment: `--save` is just a flag, a parameter for the npm command-line program. I highly suggest you read the [official doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally#using-package-json-and-the-save-flag)

Comment: so just don't ask what is it, just use? because it's a node CI command, is that right?

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

According to the npm documentation :

> --save: Package will appear in your dependencies.
>
> The --global argument will cause npm to install the package globally rather than locally.

--save will modify the `package.json` and add the dependencies in it.

--global will install the module as a global module. Every nodejs application on your machine will have this module. On most computers, the global folder of npm is in the PATH. So when you install a module as --global, you can use in a command line.